# ffnet java export example

Tags: java, python, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Does anybody have a simple example about how to export an [ffnet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffnet/) created with python to Java code?

Answer (score 1):

you need older version of ffnet (0.6.5 i guess), then you use:

```
exportnet(net, "filename.java", lang="java")
```